# Error : Cannot determine the module for class

Tags: angular

I have a directive DialogHostDirective used in one of my component DialogComponent in Module A. It is used at a ng-template tag working fine in module A.
The directive is having a ViewContainerRef used for inserting a template within the component.

I am trying to use the DialogComponent in my module B, its giving me an error:

*ERROR in Error: Cannot determine the module for class DialogHostDirective in C:/Users/jitdagar/Desktop/TDP/pwt-ui-common/src/app/components/dialog/dialog-host.directive.ts! Add DialogHostDirective to the NgModule to fix it.*

app.module for module A

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ExampleComponent,
        DialogComponent,
        DialogHostDirective,
        OpenDialogContentComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        BrowserModule,
        AlloyModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        DialogComponent,
        OpenDialogContentComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        DialogService
    ],
    exports: [ExampleComponent, DialogComponent, DialogHostDirective],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class PwtUiCommonModule {}
```

I am not declaring any component in module B as they are already declared in module A.

Answer (score 0):

You need to export all component/directives which you want to use in other modules in `exports` array of module declaration.

I believe that adding `exports: [ExampleComponent, DialogComponent, DialogHostDirective],` and possibly other required components will fix your issue.

See angular documentation: [How to declare feature modules](https://angular.io/guide/feature-modules#rendering-a-feature-modules-component-template)

Comment: I have done some more analysis and have following add-ons:  I am not calling the selector from module A but importing the component into module B using the import statement. Whichever the component I am getting the same error.Cannot determine the module for class OpenDialogContentComponent in C:/Users/jitdagar/Desktop/TDP/pwt-ui-common/src/app/components/open-dialog-content/open-dialog-content.component.ts! Add OpenDialogContentComponent to the NgModule to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am seeing a lot of these errors, but looking at the top most of my errors, it says:

> ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(72,10): Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
> Reference to a non-exported function.

I just added `export` to the function it was pointing to. After fixing that, all the other errors including this `Error : Cannot determine the module for class` went away.

Your case might be a little different, but try looking at the top most error first as it might be the root cause of the problem that prevents your module from loading correctly.